# Оптимизация кода при добавлении множества записей в Prefs

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в Android studio. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать добавление большого количества значений в Prefs?

```
...

prefEditor.putString("_syn82", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn82")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn83", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn83")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn84", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn84")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn85", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn85")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn86", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn86")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn87", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn87")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn88", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn88")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn89", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn89")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn90", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn90")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn91", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn91")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn92", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn92")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn93", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn93")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn94", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn94")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn95", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn95")));
prefEditor.putString("_syn96", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syn96")));
```

и т.д...

Comment: Похоже вы новичек в программирование, а не в Android. Читайте про циклы.

Comment: Да и зачем столько писать в преференсы, когда у Вас есть БД - работайте с ней напрямую.

Comment: откуда вы узнали про бд? можете писать в Set<String> в преференс, вроде как подойдет, а можете использовать цикл, для перебора всех значений .

Comment: Сделайте либо просто цикл с вызовом одной строки добавления и склеивайте _syn с индексом цикла, либо метод, в который будете передавать добавляемое значение (подойдет, если подобные вызовы присутствуют еще где-либо в коде)